# jquery library not working with morris.js chart plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, plugins

I've been caught in a strange situation which I never faced before. I'm building an administration panel using bootstrap template in Laravel framework. The bootstrap admin template has by default the morris.js plugins for Pie charts etc.. Today, when I tried to build a simple feature of onChange event. Then I found its not working. I tried with every angle and spent lot of time to figure out why its not working while on the other environment with same code, its working properly. So, I decided to change and remove the order of few included javascript libraries in my application. When I removed those morris.js plugin libraries, I found everything is working absolutely fine. It looks like there is some conflict within libraries or what I really don't know. Can you help me with that what really is a problem.

Here is the  tags code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>{{ $title }}</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">


<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
{{ HTML::style('packages/admin/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}

{{ HTML::style('packages/admin/bootstrap/css/datepicker.css') }}

<!-- Custom CSS -->
{{ HTML::style('packages/admin/bootstrap/css/sb-admin.css') }}

<!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
{{ HTML::style('packages/admin/bootstrap/css/plugins/morris.css') }}

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
{{ HTML::style('packages/admin/bootstrap/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}


<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
{{ HTML::script('packages/admin/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js') }}


<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
{{ HTML::script('packages/admin/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}

<!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
{{ HTML::script('packages/admin/bootstrap/js/plugins/morris/raphael.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('packages/admin/bootstrap/js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('packages/admin/bootstrap/js/plugins/morris/morris-data.js') }}

</head>
```

Comment: exactly what type of error do you get?

Comment: not any kind of error, the thing is that some bootstrap features are working while a very basic jquery <select> on Change event feature is not working.. When I remove those morris libraries, it starts working normally